# Facebook Cocoa Pods for Xcode 11/IOS 13

Tags: xcode, facebook, cocoapods

I see lots of warnings in Facebook libraries after installing Facebook Cocoa pods in xcode 11 beta 7. I am assuming I need an upgrade or different version of facebook pods for Xcode 11. Any ideas?

Just installed Pods and see lots of warnings

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

I expected to see no errors after installing Pods.